# Bug in eclipse compiler or in javac ("type parameters of T cannot be determined")

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

The following code

```
public class GenericsTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Integer i = readObject(args[0]);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static <T> T readObject(String file) throws Exception {
        return readObject(new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
        // closing the stream in finally removed to get a small example
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws Exception {
        return (T)stream.readObject();
    }
}
```

compiles in eclipse, but not with javac (type parameters of T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object).

When I change readObject(String file) to

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T readObject(String file) throws Exception {
        return (T)readObject(new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
    }
```

it compiles in eclipse and with javac. Who is correct, the eclipse compiler or javac?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'd say it's the bug in the Sun compiler reported [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6302954) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=98379), because if you change your line to the one below it works with both, which seems to be exactly what is described in the bug reports.

```
return GenericsTest2.<T>readObject(new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

Answer (score 13):

In this case, I'd say your code is wrong (and the Sun compiler is right). There is nothing in your input arguments to `readObject` to actually infer the type `T`. In that case, you're better off to let it return Object, and let clients manually cast the result type.

This should work (though I haven't tested it):

```
public static <T> T readObject(String file) throws Exception {
    return GenericsTest2.<T>readObject(new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
}
```

Comment: return GenericsTest2.<T>readObject(new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))); does work. Thanks!

Comment: I disagree, it looks more like the bug related below. The compiler should trust an explicit cast without type inference - the following compiles fine

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T createT(String className) throws Exception {
        return (T) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
    }

Answer (score 3):

Oracle JDK6 u22 should be correct but I've this problem with JDK6 u24 too

This is a bug of eclipse [bug 98379](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=98379).

This was not corrected but the problem is resolved via workaround like example in eclipse bugs (see link)

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue in java version "1.6.0_22". It disappeared when I upgraded to java version "1.6.0_32" as it was fixed in update 25.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your method readObject to work transparently when called, you may also use following:

```
public static <T> T readObject(String file, Class<T> type) throws Exception {
    return type.cast(readObject(new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))));
}
```

This way, caller is forced to specify the type of the result and compiler knows how to cast the result.