# Generics strange error: "type parameters of <T>java.util.List<? > extends T> cannot be determined"

Tags: generics, maven

I have the following piece of code, which compiles ok inside eclipse, but when running maven, I get this weird error further below.

```
 protected <T> List<? extends T> findByNamedQuery(String name, Object... args) {
       return findByNamedQuery(name, 0, 0, args);
   }
```

> /home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/comum-util/workspace/src/main/java/company/comum/dao/jpa/JpaAbstractDAO.java:[294,31]
>   type parameters of java.util.List cannot be determined; no
>   unique maximal instance exists for
>   type variable T with upper bounds
>   T,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object

Maven is configured to use java 1.6, and I also tried to configure with 1.5, but I still get the same error.

This is an existing code, which I'm just creating a maven configuration for.
The error happens when I run "mvn clean install"
Is there any thing wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: Can you give us a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem? Given that you're calling an overload here (presumably) it's tricky to see everything involved...

Answer (score 1):

Below link possibly could answer your question:

[Bug in eclipse compiler or in javac ("type parameters of T cannot be determined")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314572/bug-in-eclipse-compiler-or-in-javac)

Comment: I had seen that, but in my case I cant possibly alter the code, and both eclipse and maven are using the same jdk.
When I try running maven via eclipse I get the exact same error.

Comment: Its no real solution to the problem, but it's a workaround. Thanks!