# Creating a Parameters class using Generics

Tags: java, generics, parameters, variadic-functions

I have an interface that defines a method that does some computation

```
public interface Computable { 
    public Result compute(Foo foo);
}
```

I want to also pass in a set of arguments to the computation that can be peeled off.  I can hack this up, but I am wondering if there's an elegant solution with `generics` and `var args`.  Something like...

```
 public class Parameter<K,V> {

    private final K key;
    private final V value;

    public Parameter(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }    
}
```

But then I'm lost as to how going through each parameter from the list of parameters I would be able to simply get the key value pairs with their types inferred.  Can someone help me?  Has this not already been built into the JDK?

**EDIT with example:**

In a concrete implementation we'd have....

```
public Result compute(Foo foo,
                      Parameter ...parameters) {

    // Here I'd like to get each parameter, and have it know it's key type and value type
    for(Parameter p : parameters) {
        p.getKey();
        p.getValue()
        //implementers know what to do with their parameters
    }


}
```

Comment: Please can you post a sample of the method you want/need?

Comment: What the exception are you getting ?

Comment: You can declare interface to accept type params `public interface Computable<K,V> { ` or method to accept type params `public <K, V> void compute(Object foo, Parameter<K, V>... parameters)`

Comment: I'm not receiving an exception.  The getKey and getValue methods return objects.  I would need to explicitly cast them.  I suppose my bigger question is, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: @AmitD I was going to offer that as an answer but you should go ahead and post that.

Comment: Can someone post an example in their answer?

Answer (score 3):

As [AmitD mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283067/creating-a-parameters-class-using-generics/13283335#comment18109663_13283067), you should make `Computable` a parameterized type:

```
public interface Computable<K, V> { 
    public Result compute(Foo foo, Parameter<K, V>... parameters);
}
```

An implementation would then resolve `K` and `V` and the types would be known:

```
public class BarBazComputable implements Computable<Bar, Baz> {
    @Override
    public Result compute(Foo foo, Parameter<Bar, Baz>... parameters) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edit:** And yes, as AmitD mentioned again, you're not required to resolve either or all of the type parameters:

```
public class WithStringComputable<K> implements Computable<K, String> {
    @Override
    public Result compute(Foo foo, Parameter<K, String>... parameters) {
        ...
    }
}

public class OhJustACoupleObjectsComputable<K, V> implements Computable<K, V> {
    @Override
    public Result compute(Foo foo, Parameter<K, V>... parameters) {
        ...
    }
}

public class NumbersComputable<N1 extends Number, N2 extends Number> implements Computable<N1, N2> {
    @Override
    public Result compute(Foo foo, Parameter<N1, N2>... parameters) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that varargs don't play nice with generics, and you will get a type-safety warning at the callsite when invoking `compute`. Instead, consider having the method take an `Iterable<Parameter<K, V>>`.

Comment: But then doesn't this mean I can only have Parameters with keys that are Bars, and Values that are Baz's?

Comment: I appreciate the answer and I am upvoting.  I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for yet.

Comment: @AmirAfghani which is correct because if you want less specific types then you can use Parent classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different key types for the different parameters or different value types, you probably won't be able to solve this with a simple generic varargs function definition. Your only type-safe option would then be something like this:

```
public Result compute(Foo foo, Parameter<Byte, Byte> p1, Parameter<Byte, Float> p2, ...)
```

(here "..." denotes further parameters added in the same way, not the varargs ellipses)

.

If you need to be flexible, though, and you can determine which key and value type you are dealing with by probing some other property of the Parameter, there's a trick I sometimes use to simplify the type-casting: Change your `getKey()` function in the `Parameter` class to this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <KeyType> KeyType getKey() {
    return (KeyType) this.key;
}
```

(and similarly for the getValue() function)

That way, you can simply assign the results of `getKey()` to a variable of any (non-primitive) type, like this:

```
Integer key = parameter.getKey();
```

or

```
String key = parameter.getKey();
```

and you won't have to do any type casting in your compute function, and there won't be any warnings.

**But: You will loose the compile-time type-check!** So, you have to make sure at runtime (which you might have to anyway) that you don't assign a key to a variable with a wrong type. Or at least handle the resulting ClassCastException gracefully.

Comment: or if you know for sure that your key is a subtype of some other type, like K in your example, you can get at least that bit of type-safety by using: public <KeyType extends K> KeyType getKey() {...

Comment: What does the KeyType class look like?

Comment: @AmirAfghani It's not a class. It's simply a placeholder that says "whatever you assign it to"

Comment: It's a generic function defintion. You could for example do this: public <MyNum extends Number> MyNum add(MyNum x, MyNum y) ... That enforces that you pass the same number type for x and y and says that the return type is also the same, but you don't need to say beforehand what MyNum is.

Comment: @AmirAfghani No worries, it took me a sec to get that the first time I saw it as well... BTW: There is one case where the compiler isn't smart enough to treat this 100% right and will sometimes throw an exception: If you have a generic function that calls another generic function, it sometimes doesn't resolve the "indirection" right. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666027/why-does-the-compiler-state-no-unique-maximal-instance-exists. Cheers.