# Android jenkins build error

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, ormlite

I am using jenkins to build an Android library project that uses ORMLite and i am getting the following error which i really don't know how to solve :

```
[javac] /Users/x/Desktop/workspace/x/src/com/x/x/database/DatabaseHelper.java:109:
    type parameters of <D>D cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists
    for type variable D with upper bounds com.x.x.database.dao.DatabaseObjectDao,
    com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao<com.x.x.database.entity.UserEntity,?>
[javac] sUserEntityDao = getDao(UserEntity.class);
```

Any help would be really great :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the compiler state no unique maximal instance exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666027/why-does-the-compiler-state-no-unique-maximal-instance-exists)

Answer (score 0):

So the below is probably wrong but I'll leave it for posterity.  I initially thought this was an ORMLite error but now I think it is a compiler error.

I think you should look at this question/answer:

> [Why does the compiler state no unique maximal instance exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666027/why-does-the-compiler-state-no-unique-maximal-instance-exists)

---

This may be an [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) error if part of the exception tree may have have some message to the effect of:

```
Could not find OpenHelperClass because none of the generic parameters of class 
YourActivityClass extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.  You should use
getHelper(Context, Class) instead.
```

The simple ORMLite pattern for Android applications is to have activity extend `OrmLiteBaseActivity<YourDatabaseHelper>`.  Something like:

```
public class HelloAndroid extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper> {
```

Then when you call `getHelper()`, ORMLite can figure out automagically which `DatabaseHelper` helper class to use.  There are other ways to setup the wiring for ORMLite.  I'd take a look at the [Android starting docs](http://ormlite.com/docs/android) and then take a look at the [Android example programs](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples).