# javac compiler discrepancies

Tags: java, generics, javac

**Update:** this seems to be Eclipse-related, rather than Hudson-related so I updated the question accordingly.

I'm getting some compiler errors when running Maven on the command line, but all developers in our group has the code working fine in Eclipse (some Generic intricacies, see below for details). How could this differ and what to do about it?

The code that fails looks like this:

```
299 private <T extends ProductClassDTO> List<T> convertProductClass(List<? extends ProductClassDTO> fromList) {
300     List<T> toList = new ArrayList<T>();
301     for (ProductClassDTO from : fromList) {
302         T to = convert(from);
303         toList.add(to);
304     }
305     return toList;
306 }
```

this is the error on build server:

```
[ERROR] ...java:[302,26] type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,com.volvo.protom.util.dto.ProductClassDTO
```

(I know there are other questions+answers on this in SO, but they don't seem to apply to this particular question, since changing to `T to = <T>convert(from)` doesn't work, perhaps I should do something else?) I'm guessing the error refers to that there are several `convert` methods in this class, and more than one fit?

Thanks!

**Update 2:** these are the convert signatures:

```
private void convert(TestObjectDTO from, TestObjectDTO to);
private <T extends TestObjectDTO> T convert(TestObjectDTO from);
private void convert(ProductClassDTO from, ProductClassDTO to);
private <T extends ProductClassDTO> T convert(ProductClassDTO from);
private void convert(TestObjectTypeDTO from, TestObjectTypeDTO to);
private <T extends TestObjectTypeDTO> T convert(TestObjectTypeDTO from);
```

Comment: This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314572/bug-in-eclipse-compiler-or-in-javac

Comment: It is, but as I mentioned adding <T> to line 302 does not work in the compiler we developers use under Windows.

Comment: What are the signatures for the `convert` methods?

Comment: @McDowell: I updated the question with the convert method signatures. As you see the 4th from the top is the one I'm trying to call from convertProductClass().

Comment: I was able to circumvent the problem by simply casting: `T to = (T) convert(from);`, but that's hopefully not the nicest solution...

Comment: I would expect `this.<T>convert(from);` to work.

Comment: I can't say what to do about it but I can tell why it's different - Eclipse doesn't use Java compiler from JDK, it has it's own so there were/is/could be discrepancies, albeit pretty rare these days. I personally observed few times in the past when code was compiling in Eclipse and not in JDK or vise versa. That's why it's always important to have your build on CI server, outside of your IDE.

Comment: I found Eclipse to be correct and javac to have a couple of bugs, but we were able to work around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse and JDK javac are slightly different, see [@maximdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49573/maximdim)'s comment. Always run from the command-line to ensure compatibility (though Eclipse's javac seems more correct).

Answer (score -1):

I guess the signatures of these methods are not what they should be. Generic methods where the generic parameter occurs *only* in the return type (like in `<T extends ProductClassDTO> T convert(ProductClassDTO)`) are usually not what you want.

What this means is, that it is legal for the caller to call the method and cast the result to any possible sub-type of `ProductClassDTO`. Usually there is only one possible value that fulfills this requirement: `null`. So the convert methods would always have to return `null` to be type safe. Otherwise `ClassCastException`s may occur in the calling code.

Remember that due to type erasure, the `convert` methods have no chance of knowing which type the caller wants the `T` to be, so they can't return instances of different types according to the value of `T`.

The same problem occurs for the `convertProductClass` method, although it is not that bad here. This method is required to return a list, which contains only such values which the caller is free to interpret as any subtype of `ProductClassDTO`. The only values which fulfill this are `null`, the empty list, and lists containing only `null` values. All other cases might lead to a `ClassCastException` somewhere when the list is used.

What you can do:

- If the convert methods return always the same type, change the return
  type of the methods to this type.
- If the callers don't care about the concrete type but just need to know that it is a sub-type of `ProductClassDTO`, change the return types to `ProductClassDTO` and `List<ProductClassDTO>`, respectively.
- If the `convert` methods should return instances of types according to the wish of the caller, you need to explicitly tell them the type to return by passing an instance of `Class<T>` as an additional parameter to all of these methods. Then the `convert` methods can use this object to create new instances of the appropriate types.

Comment: If I assign it to an implementing class of ProductClassDTO (which is an interface), it works. Passing Class<T> is what I want to avoid, hence no such thing. List<ProductClassDTO> requires casting if I want some other type (via List<?>), which becomes lengthy. Casting to T solved the problem anyway, so I'll stick with that instead of adding heaps of unnecessary code.

Comment: @Jonas It works now, because the caller and the convert methods just happen to use the same value for `T`. But your compiler gives warnings, because it might break some day when you change one of them (and there won't be any compiler warnings or errors at that time, just an exception at runtime). So I suggest adding the code now, saving you a debugging session later.

Comment: Furthermore, if both caller and convert methods agree, why don't you just use `ProductClassDTO` as the return type? Or the implementing type of it? I can't see a reason not to this from your explanations.

Comment: That would require "external" casts in a dozen places, so better to keep a single runtime exception than a dozen is my reasoning. ;)