# Generics compilation error

Tags: java, android, generics, intellij-idea, ormlite

Error appears in android project using ormlite
I get compilation error on this code:

```
public class DatabaseModel {
        private Dao<Object, Integer> mDao = null;
        private DatabaseHelper mHelper;
        private Class<?> mClass;

        public DatabaseModel(DatabaseHelper h, Class<?> c) {
                mHelper = h;
                mClass = c;
                try {
                        mDao = mHelper.getDao(mClass);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        Debug.e("Can't get dao", e.getStackTrace());
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
        }

on line 25 mDao = mHelper.getDao(mClass);

Error: type parameters of <D>D cannot be determined; no unique maximal
instance exists for type variable D with upper bounds
     com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer>,
     com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao<capture#296 of ?,?>
```

But when i tries to build project using eclipse it works fine

The error looks similar [to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314572/bug-in-eclipse-compiler-or-in-javac).

I don't know  whether this bug of Idea or javac.

My configuration:
IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.2
Build #IC-111.277
Built on 1 Февраль 2012 г.
JDK: 1.6.0_29
VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor: Apple Inc.

Comment: I'd like to have a look at the `DatabaseHelper.getDao()` method.

Comment: ofcourse! u can download sources from http://ormlite.com/

Comment: But there are no classes called DatabaseHelper.

Comment: this is a part of android package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting this error in eclipse but I can see why you would see a problem.  `mdao` is defined as `Dao<Object, Integer>` but you are calling `getDao(mClass)` where `mclass` is a `Class<?>`.  Object != ? in generic land.

You could turn your entire class into a generic type.  Something like the following would work.

```
public class DatabaseModel<T, ID> {
    private Dao<T, ID> mDao = null;
    private DatabaseHelper mHelper;
    private Class<T> mClass;

    public DatabaseModel(DatabaseHelper h, Class<T> c) {
        mHelper = h;
        mClass = c;
        try {
            mDao = mHelper.getDao(mClass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Debug.e("Can't get dao", e.getStackTrace());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing i can not understand, why Idea is not able to compile this, but eclipse cat

Comment: No idea.  It may be that Eclipse is just more lenient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could circumvent the problem by using `getDataDao()` instead of `getDao()`.