# Simplest way to cast a Class<T> to a Class<E extends Enum<E>> without losing type information

Tags: java, generics, casting, enums

I have a method `createFoo()` that creates instances of `Foo<T>` using the `Class<T>` instance for that `T`. Now I want to extend that method to forward calls that are made using an enum type to the method `createEnumFoo()`. Calling the second method from the first one seems to be non-trivial. Below is an example of how I managed to do it using two unchecked casts and an extra method, all of which I would like to get rid of.

The method `castEnumType()` is required because I couldn't find a way to cast a `Class<?>` to a `Class<E extends Enum<E>>` without having the `E` bound somewhere. This involves an unchecked cast because I have not found a way to do it using `Class.asSubclass()`. After creating the instance of `Foo`, I need to cast it from `Foo<E>` to `Foo<T>` event though `E` and `T` will always be the same types.

I can't weaken the signature of `createEnumFoo()` because it is calling `Enum.valueOf(enumType, ...)` and requires the result of this to be of type `E`.

```
final class Example {
    <E extends Enum<E>> Foo<E> createEnumFoo(Class<E> enumType) {
        // This makes use of e.g. Enum.valueOf(enumType, ...).
        return null;
    }

    <E extends Enum<E>> Class<E> castEnumType(Class<?> enumType) {
        return (Class<E>) enumType;
    }

    <T> Foo<T> createFoo(Class<T> type) {
        if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
            return (Foo<T>) createEnumFoo(castEnumType(type));
        else
            // Here we would do something else or maybe throw an exception.
            return null;
    }

    interface Foo<T> {
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

---

#### Some context

*To clarify the problem I'm facing, I'll explain how this problem actually arose in a project I'm working on:*

In the code where I came across this problem, `Foo<T>` is actually `Converter<T>`, which is an interface which allows an instance of `T` to be serialized and de-serialized from and to a *JSON* value:

```
public interface Converter<T> {
    JsonObject encode(T value);

    T decode(JsonObject data);
}
```

And `createFoo()` is actually a method `converterForType()` which takes a `Class<T>` instance and dynamically dispatches to a bunch of static methods and fields that create/contain converters for common Java types and types specific to the project. Normally when a converter is needed, the appropriate method/field is accessed directly but there are some places where the type is only known at runtime, which is where `converterForType()` is used.

Now I wanted to extend that method to automatically handle enum types by converting those to JSON strings containing the name of the enum constant. This is why I need to call the method `enumConverter()` from `converterForType()`. This is the implementation of `enumConverter()`:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> Converter<E> enumConverter(final Class<E> enumClass) {
    return new Converter<E>() {
        public JsonObject encode(E value) {
            return Json.convert(value.name());
        }

        public E decode(JsonObject data) {
            return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, data.asString());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better way. See this related post: [Passing a runtime resolved parameter to a method which has multiple bound type, compilation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978730/passing-a-runtime-resolved-parameter-to-a-method-which-has-multiple-bound-type). How are you actually returning the enum instance though? Depending, you could just use `Class.getEnumConstants()`. Let me know if I should expand on that with an answer.

Comment: Can you show an example of creating the `Foo` with the Enum class?

Comment: @PaulBellora @Radiodef I added a description of where this problem actually came up in a project. Accessing the enum constants from given the `Class<E>` instance is not an issue, if I call `enumConverter()` directly.

Answer (score 2):

What about this, use raw types for createEnumFoo method

Edit: fixed compile error reported by @Feuermurmel in comments

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
final class Example
{
    <E extends Enum<E>> Foo<E> createEnumFoo(Class enumType)
    {
        // This makes use of e.g. Enum.valueOf(enumType, ...).
        Enum x = Enum.valueOf(enumType, "x");
        return (Foo<E>) x;
    }

    <T extends Enum> Foo<T> createFoo(Class<T> type)
    {
        if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
            return (Foo<T>) createEnumFoo(type);
        else
            // Here we would do something else or maybe throw an exception.
            return null;
    }

    interface Foo<T>
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you are right. I can probably just as well use raw types if I can't avoid unchecked casts. But I instead added a cast to `Class` at the call site of `createEnumFoo()` instead of weakening that method's signature: `return (Foo<T>) createEnumFoo((Class) type);`. BTW: `createEnumFoo()` cannot return an `Enum<?>`, as you do in your code, it needs to return some `Foo<E>`. Can you fix that?

Comment: My code compiles correctly in eclipse (java 7).
`<E extends Enum<E>> Foo<E> createEnumFoo(Class enumType)
 {
  // This makes use of e.g. Enum.valueOf(enumType, ...).
  Foo<E> foo =Enum.valueOf(enumType, "x"); 
  return foo;
 }`

Comment: When I copy and paste the code in your answer into a file called `Example.java` and run `javac Example.java`, it prints the following error: `Example.java:7: error:incompatible types`. See here: https://ideone.com/zaYv7B

Comment: I know it's beent four years, but I fixed the compile error :)